# What was the average price of EOS during the 1 year ICO sale during 2017-2018?

Tags: ico

I read that the ICO sale for EOS fluctuated depending on demand and there wasn't a fixed price. Was there a base fixed price at all? And what was the average eos price by the time it ended? And when did it end exactly?

Comment: no fixed price. fluctuated between $0.5 and $20, but not sure about average. ended on 1st of june